# MEAN stack (with Angular Material) - Convert xhr response in javascript array

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I am building a MEAN web app.

I handle routes on the Express side and I have the following :

```
    router.get('/list', function(req, res) {
    Fruit.find(function(err, fruits) {
        if(err)
            handleError(res, err.message, "Could not retrieve fruit list");
        else
            res.status(200).json(fruits);
    });
}
```

Fruits are Mongo documents constructed as follows :

```
    {
  « _id »: ObjectId,
  « name »: String
}
```

From my angular controller I am trying to use a function defined as follows :

```
function loadFruits() {
            var promise = $http.get("/list");
            var tmp = promise.then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    return tmp;
}
```

On the front-end side I would like to display the list of fruits but I cannot manage to cast response.data into a javascript array usable.

When I inspect the response (via Google Chrome Inspector) I can see that the express response is of type xhr.

I have tried several things like :

- JSON.parse() —> which returns an error because it looks like the object has already been parsed
- angular.fromJSON() —> could make it work
  etc.

For more accuracy, here is what the xhr response looks like in the inspector:

```
[{"_id":"581757f66c9e4c768c8eb648","name":"fruit1"},
"_id":"581758146c9e4c768c8eb649","name":"fruit2"},
"_id":"5817582c6c9e4c768c8eb64a","name":"fruit3"}]
```

Would you have any idea of how I can easily transform the response.data into a javascript array usable on the front-end?

Preview in the inspector gives me a different representation:

```
[{_id: "581757f66c9e4c768c8eb648", name: "fruit1"},…]
0
:
{_id: "581757f66c9e4c768c8eb648", name: "fruit1"}
1
:
{_id: "581758146c9e4c768c8eb649", name: "fruit2"}
2
:
{_id: "5817582c6c9e4c768c8eb64a", name: "fruit3"}
```

Thanks a lot!

**** update ****
Here is what I get in the console with the following code (fyi tmp.data returns undedined):

```
    var promise = $http.get("/api/sports/list");
    var tmp = promise.then(function(response) {
        return response;
    });
```

[image: tmp variable]

Comment: I removed the `angular-material` tab as it's not AM related. Hope that's okay.

Comment: Is there any chance the response object itself is already the array and you are returning response.data instead? ..

Comment: Roberto, I have updated my post with a screenshot of the content of the response object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but you seem to have the data in a "$$state.value" object, that being the case, the below code should work.

```
var promise = $http.get("/api/sports/list");
var tmp = promise.then(function(response) {
    return response.$$state.value.data;
});
```